# Pass MYSQL row id to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have this script which is triggered when a button with the class `.press_me` is pressed.The buttons are on a column from a php generated mysql table:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbname");
echo "<table id='main'>"; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='right-middle user'>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='right-middle user'>" . $row['Nume'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='right-middle done'>" . $row['Teme_facute'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='right-middle check'>" . "<img src='img/check.png' class='press_me'>" ."</td>";
echo "<td class='right-middle undone'>" . $row['Teme_nefacute'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='right-middle uncheck'>" . "<img src='img/uncheck.png'>" . "</td>";
echo "<td class='side-table resetDone'>" . "<img src='img/resetDone.png'>" . "</td>";
echo "<td class='side-table resetUndone'>" . "<img src='img/resetUndone.png'>" . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

And the script:

```
<script>
   $(function (){
            $('.press_me').click(function(){
        var id=<?php echo json_decode('$row[ID]'); ?>;          
            var request = $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "counter.php"
                                  });
                                  request.done(function( msg ) {

                                        alert('Success');
                                       location.reload();
                                        return;

                                  });
                                  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                                        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                                    });
            });
    }); 
    </script>
```

And `counter.php`:

```
<?php
echo $_POST["id"];
if(!empty($_POST["id"]))
{
    $id = $_POST["id"];

    $connection=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        exit;
    }

    mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE tbname SET amount= (amount+ 1) WHERE ID = '" . $id . "'");

    mysqli_close($connection);
    echo 'OK';
}
else
{
    echo 'NO ID PASSED';
}
?>
```

I'm having trouble updating only the value on the same row as the button pressed.When i run the page in this configuration `counter.php` returns **no id passed** and i think the problem is with the passing of the row id. Can anyone help me update only the value on the row with the pressed button?

I'm aware of sql injection but it's not the main problem now

Comment: Try this: **var id="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>";** and in the $.ajax construct **data:id,**

Comment: @hherger still returns nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your id is empty
try this

```
echo "<td class='right-middle check'>" . "<img data-id='{$row['ID']}' src='img/check.png' class='press_me'>" ."</td>";
```

And in the script use this

```
  var id=$(this).data("id");
```

Comment: it works, it returns the row id, but the value doesn't seem to change. should i modify sth in `counter.php` aswell?

Comment: try this "UPDATE tbname SET amount= amount+ 1 WHERE ID =  $id"

Comment: unfortunately the values still don't increase

Comment: @AlexResiga Look at Rafai lAkhmetshin answer, that is also one of your problems

Comment: echo this "UPDATE tbname SET amount= amount+ 1 WHERE ID = $id" in your code and whats result???

Comment: @paranoid it works now,i just had to include `data: { id: id}` in the ajax request. thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

change you javascript, looks like you are not sending data at all

```
<script>
   $(function (){
            $('.press_me').click(function(){
        var id=<?php echo json_decode('$row[ID]'); ?>;          
            var request = $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "counter.php",
                                    // add this line
                                    data: { id: id}
                                  });
                                  request.done(function( msg ) {

                                        alert('Success');
                                       location.reload();
                                        return;

                                  });
                                  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                                        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                                    });
            });
    }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: This is also a required change

Comment: thank you so much, you and @paranoid both solved my problem and i don't know whose answer should i mark as verified

Answer (score 0):

Replace below script:

```
<script>
 $(function (){
    $('.press_me').click(function(){
      var id=<?php echo $row[ID]; ?>;          
          var request = $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "counter.php"
                        });
        request.done(function( msg ) {

              alert('Success');
             location.reload();
              return;

        });
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
              alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
          });
  });
}); 
</script>
```

> NOTE: I assume that you are working with single record. If not then it
>   will going wrong.

If this is working wrong then replace `.press_me` line with below:

```
$id = $row['ID'];
echo "<td class='right-middle check'>" . "<img src='img/check.png' class='press_me' id='<?php print($id);?>' >" ."</td>";
```

And script is like:

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
```

Hope this help you well!

Comment: Not really going to help much, you did spot that there will be more than one `$row['id']`  as that is collected in a while loop from a multi row result set? _Or maybe not_

Comment: He is not working with **single record** This **will go wrong**

Comment: well i hoped that he knows to get the row id of the row of the pressed button

Comment: You do realise that `id="???"` has a specific meaning and use in the DOM, you might want to use a slightly different name to `id`